# How to fix "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError" on kafka-start-server.sh

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to install `kafka` on `Cloudera` quickstart vm. I have done all the steps. But I am getting the following error, while starting the `kafka` server:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/kafka/common/utils/KafkaThread : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

I have following environment variables set within my `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin:$PATH"

export KAFKA_HOME="/opt/kafka/kafka_2.11-2.2.0"
export PATH="$KAFKA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

export KAFKA_CLASSPATH="$KAFKA_HOME/libs/"
export KAFKA_CONF_DIR="$KAFKA_HOME/config/"
```

I have tried using both `java 7` and `java 8` but the error still persists.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The error means you don't use java 8 but older version. can you try running `java --version` before the script?

Comment: You're using an older version of Java (pre-8) at runtime. Are you sure your path is being updated?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka tries to find Java command at `JAVA_HOME`

Try

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_211
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

kafka-server-start server.properties
```

Note: You don't need a Hadoop environment to run Kafka, so just a fresh VM with Java 8 (or 11) would work with latest Kafka.

Or you could use Docker

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 points to Java 8. It means that the Kafka Version you have installed needs Java 8 to function properly.

Refer below for other versions:

Java 1.2 uses major version 46,
Java 1.3 uses major version 47,
Java 1.4 uses major version 48,
Java 5 uses major version 49,
Java 6 uses major version 50,
Java 7 uses major version 51,
**Java 8 uses major version 52**,
Java 9 uses major version 53,
Java 10 uses major version 54,
Java 11 uses major version 55,
Java 12 uses major version 56,
Java 13 uses major version 57,
Java 14 uses major version 58

Follow these steps and it should work:

1. Make sure which version of Java you have installed by typing java -version and correspondingly map the version according to the error message you receive from Kafka Start Script.
2. Type **which java** and get the path where Java is installed in your system.

Example: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el6_10.x86_64/jdk/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java

3. Go to base directory and edit .bashrc file and add the below three lines.

1st line: The path in step 2 before bin has to be assigned to JAVA_HOME.

Example: **export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el6_10.x86_64/jdk/jdk1.8.0_221**

2nd line: **PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH**

3rd line: **export PATH**

4. Source .bashrc file by executing the following command:

**source .bashrc**

5. Then go to Kafka installed folder and execute the below command and it should work:

bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

Enjoy coding!